# Pgfplots does not load data table

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I am relatively new to LaTeX, and I am trying to include plots with the help of pgfplots. The problem I have is very basic, and therefore very confusing for me.
Plotting a simple graph from a table included in the .tex file works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}

\pgfplotstableread{
1   1   2
2   2   4
3   3   8
}\datatable

\addplot table[y index = 2] from \datatable ;
\addplot table[y index = 1] from \datatable ;

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But If I copy/paste the table into a data.dat file in the same folder as the .tex file, and change the code to

```
\pgfplotstableread{data.dat}\datatable
```

I get an error message: 
    Could not read table file 'data.dat' in 'search path=.'.

I have no idea where the mistake is, and I would be very grateful for any tips and help!

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Where do you place the file `data.dat`?

Comment: I put it in the same folder in which the .tex file is. Do I have to specify a path in the .tex file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me when I use your example. I changed your \pgfplotsset{compat=1.14} to \pgfplotsset{compat=newest} but that should not make a difference.

Make sure that you actually save the file as a data.dat and not data.dat.txt.

Comment: I feel stupid now. Thank you! I accidentally saved it as data.dat.txt